# Can I automate tar's multi-volume-feature?

Tags: bash, backup, cron, tar, split

Ok, so I've just had a read through [this page](http://trulymanaged.com/blog/how-to-split-a-large-files-to-multiple-parts-using-tar/) after a way to improve my current backup solution on my Debian server. Tar seems to be offering a quite nice multi-volume feature, although when I try it out, it asks me to `Prepare volume #X for ‘mybackup.tar.gz’ and hit return:`.

How should I automate this as I would like to take usage of this feature in an automated CRON script where no one is there to push return and enter whatever is rquired by the multi-volume prompt.

Is using `split` the only way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
printf 'n file-%02d.tar\n' {2..100} | 
    tar -ML 716800 -cf file-01.tar Documents/ 2>/dev/null
```

where 100 is a number greater or equal to the number of volumes.

**Edit**

Setting a big number should not be a problem, though I tend to not take a ridiculous one.

An alternative could be a ["next volume" script](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#info_002dscript), that you can set with the `-F` option,

```
tar -ML 716800 -F './myscript file' -cf file.tar Documents/ 2>/dev/null
```

then in `./myscript` put

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix="$1"
n=1
while [[ -e "$prefix-$n.tar" ]]; do
  ((n++))
done
mv "$prefix.tar" "$prefix-$n.tar"
echo "$prefix-$n.tar"
```

It will be executed at each volume end, and will move `file.tar` to the appropriate `fileNNN.tar`. For the last volume the script will not be executed, so the last volume name stay `file.tar`.

**Edit 2**

I ended up with the following elaborated solution.
Here are two script, one for the creation and the other for the extraction:

```
#!/bin/bash
# CREATION SCRIPT

# save on file the initial volume number
echo 1 >number

# multi-volume archive creation
tar -ML 100000 -F './tar-multi-volume-script c file' -cf file.tar Documents2/ 2>&-

# execute the "change-volume" script a last time
./tar-multi-volume-script c file
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
# EXTRACTION SCRIPT

# save on file the initial volume number
echo 1 >number

# execute the "change-volume" script a first time
./tar-multi-volume-script x file

# multi-volume archive extraction
tar -M -F './tar-multi-volume-script x file' -xf file.tar 2>&-

# remove a spurious file
rm file.tar
```

where `./tar-multi-volume-script` is given by

```
#!/bin/bash
# TAR INVOKED SCRIPT

mode="$1"
prefix="$2"
n=$(<number)

case $mode in
  c) mv "$prefix.tar"    "$prefix-$n.tar" ;;
  x) cp "$prefix-$n.tar" "$prefix.tar"    ;;
esac

echo $((n+1)) >number
```

Obviously you have to change many bits here and there to adapt to your situation and to be sure it would work in `cron`, that is always a little challenge.

Comment: I like that, but then I need to know the max number of volumes per directory in beforehand? I mean, what happens when I exceed 716m in 100 directories? Can I just set max to a ridiculously high number like 919191 and leave it?

Comment: @Industrial: see edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer, Enzotib! How would you suggest restoring/extracting using this "next-volume" script?

Comment: @Industrial: here an almost complete solution

Comment: Great approaches! Thanks to everyone involved. -- Caveat: I can see that the first solution uses a `bash` built-in feature called __brace expansion__; this may not be available in all shells. Should you run into an error message or unexpected behavior, use `printf 'n file-%02d.tar\n' $(seq 2 100) | (etc.)` instead, which ought to work anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. How to make the external command/next volume script launch a command in a subshell, without letting tar wait for that new subshell to be done?

Comment: Self-answer: use `screen -m -d`, stupid: http://superuser.com/a/172052/283120 Try with

$ cat next.sh
#!/bin/bash

screen -d -m sh -c "sleep 10s; date > /tmp/test; exit"
$ tar cf test.tar -ML 10k -F "./next.sh" testinput

Comment: From the tar man page you linked, you could use `$TAR_ARCHIVE-$TAR_VOLUME` in your next-volume-script.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the manual ...

http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Multi_002dVolume-Archives.html

or simply use the following search string at your favorite internet search engine:

**"Archives Longer than One Tape or Disk"**

That section of the GNU **tar** manual provides a suitable script (called *new-volume*) to use with the **-F** option of the tar command. You could tweak that script to your taste if you wish.

enjoy!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to mention the `--new-volume-script` flag?

Comment: Please don't just post links; include some context so that, should the other site go down, there is sufficient information here to make sense of your answer.