# Proper way to join multi-volume tarballs?

Tags: tar

So how should this be done? I have learned that using `cat` is the preferred way when using `split` to create multi-volume files, but what about when using `tar`'s own native multi-volume function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21373/can-i-automate-tars-multi-volume-feature/21374#21374) I give an answer using a callback script, to be used with the `-F` option of `tar`.

Here I expand on the automated input to tar prompt requests, both in the creation and the extraction of the archive, and estimating in advance the number of volumes needed:

```
#!/bin/bash
# CREATION SCRIPT

vol_size=100000

# estimated number of volumes: dir-size / vol-size + 1
# adding a further +1 to be safe
n=$(($(du -s Documents2 | awk '{ print $1 }') / $vol_size + 2))

for ((i = 2; i <= n; i++)); do printf 'n file-%d.tar\n' $i; done |
  tar -ML $vol_size -cf file-1.tar Documents2/ 2>&-
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
# EXTRACTION SCRIPT

n=$(printf '%s\n' file-*.tar | sed 's/^file-//;s/\.tar$//' | sort -nr | head -1)
for ((i = 2; i <= n; i++)); do printf 'n file-%d.tar\n' $i; done |
  tar -M -xf file-1.tar 2>&-
```

Comment: Hi again :) The extraction script just seems to freak out, so I removed the "to null bit in the end" and found out that it says (freely translated from Swedish to English) `Prepare volume 2 for file-20.tar and press carriage return: tar file end on expected user answer. Tar: Error can not be handled, exiting`. Any ideas? :)

Comment: @Industrial: you are right, there was an error: the two for loops should begin from 2, not 1. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Hi again! You are really amazing helping me out with this. I have absolutely no idea on what to do now. I managed to get the script running properly at my Ubuntu 10.04 workstation, but when I deploy it to the Debian server where it is meant to live, I get this error: `Prepare volume #2 for "file-4.tar" and hit return: tar: EOF where user reply was expected
tar: WARNING: Archive is incomplete
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`.